# MVC Pass element id from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, file, element

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("PreviewImage", "Music", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <input type="file" class="upload-image" id="upload-image-file_@item.Id" name="file" accept="image/*">
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="bt_@item.Id" style="display: none" type="submit"></button>
    }
}
```

How do I pass the file id to the controller?

Comment: Need clarification - Do you want to pass the file path to the controller once they select the file from their system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that you want to pass back the path of the image uploaded - Inside of your controller, use the following:

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
{
         var file = Request.Files[0];

         if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
         {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var serverPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(serverPath);

         }
}
```

Under the assumption that you are talking about the `@item.Id` variable you are appending the `Id`, I would add `@item.Id` here:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("PreviewImage", "Music", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data", @itemId = @item.Id }))
```

And then make the corresponding changes to your controller.

Comment: I need to pass "upload-image-file_@item.Id" to the controller. Is this possible to do? I know how to pass model Id's but I was wondering if you could do it with elements.

Comment: You can just append "upload-image-file_" to the id that you pass through the BeginForm call.

Comment: Thanks alot. Did that and then PreviewImage/" + @item.Id.ToString() to get correct form id in controller.